# Do not redirect API request to login page if bearer token is missing in authorisation header

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I'm writing a Spring Boot application with Spring Security which has a REST API and a web interface. When a user is not authenticated, the REST API should just return `401 Unauthorized` whereas the web interface should redirect to the login page. With the configuration below, this is working in the following situations:

- If the bearer token is invalid or expired
- If no authorization header is present

What I can't manage to do is to have the same behaviour if the request contains an authorisation header but *no* `bearer` token. In this case, requests are always redirected to the login page, regardless of whether it is an API request or a "web" request. The only option to prevent that I've found so far is to set `bearer-only` to true, but then no request would be redirected to the login page anymore...

Is there any other configuration I could try? Thx!

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = [KeycloakSecurityComponents::class])
open class SecurityConfiguration : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    open fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver {
        return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
    }

    @Bean
    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
        return RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())
    }

    override fun authenticationEntryPoint(): AuthenticationEntryPoint? {
        val requestMatcher = NegatedRequestMatcher(
            OrRequestMatcher(
                WEBAPP_ANT_PATHS.map {
                    AntPathRequestMatcher(it)
                }
            )
        )

        return KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint(adapterDeploymentContext(), requestMatcher)
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
    }

    companion object {
        val WEBAPP_ANT_PATHS = listOf("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security's `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` (and the corresponding `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint`) is triggered when there is a bearer token.

If you want to invoke the `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint` at other times, you can register it with the global exception handler:

```java
http
    .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
    );
```

And this will tell Spring Security to use the `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint` for any `AuthenticationException`.

Or, if you are supporting more than one authentication mechanism (like form login, too), then you can specify a `RequestMatcher`:

```java
http
    .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
            new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint(),
            (request) -> request.getHeader("Authorization") != null
        )
    );
```

That said, you may find more success by using Spring Security without the Keycloak wrapper. The reason for this is that Spring Security now ships with [its own bearer token support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver).